# how to get particular JSON object in accordance with another value of object?

Tags: android, json, object

I've json array like this:

```
{"GetReportResult":
  [
   {"bulan":"4","total":"2448","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"8847823"}, 
   {"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL","uang":"5863408410"},
   {"bulan":"4","total":"46008","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"234498301"},
   {"bulan":"5","total":"5703","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"134929306"},
   {"bulan":"5","total":"648663","type":"ESL","uang":"6645764498"},
   {"bulan":"5","total":"51958","type":"WHP","uang":"631994613"},
   {"bulan":"6","total":"6190","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"104527773"},
   {"bulan":"6","total":"443335","type":"ESL","uang":"4540123082"},
   {"bulan":"6","total":"30550","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"148302378"},
  ]
}
```

and this is the code that I want to get certain object:

```
JSONArray  weeklyflash = json.getJSONArray("GetReportResult");
JSONObject e = weeklyflash.getJSONObject(i);     
String bulan = e.getString("bulan");

if (bulan == 6){
     map.put("total1", e.getString("total")); // I want the "total" values are from specified bulan (e.g. bulan == 6)
}
else if (bulan == 5){
     map.put("total2", e.getString("total")); // I want the "total" values are from specified bulan (e.g. bulan == 5)
}
else if (bulan == 4){
      map.put("total3", e.getString("total")); // I want the "total" values are from specified bulan (e.g. bulan == 4)
}
```

what I got is like this:

```
  total1  |   total2   |  total3
----------------------------------
  2448    |   2448     |  2448
  572476  |   572476   |  572476
  46008   |   46008    |  46008
```

I want to get values that comes from specified object value (e.g. I want to get all values from `"total"` where `"bulan"` = 5). How to do that? 
and what I want is like this:

```
  total1  |   total2   |  total3
----------------------------------
  6190    |   5703     |  2448
  443335  |   648663   |  572476
  30550   |   51958    |  46008
```

Comment: The problem with your code is your are overwriting map values.see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
try {
    ArrayList < String > listBulan4 = new ArrayList < String > ();
    ArrayList < String > listBulan5 = new ArrayList < String > ();
    ArrayList < String > listBulan6 = new ArrayList < String > ();

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonString");

    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetReportResult");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

        int bulanValue = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("bulan"));

        switch (bulanValue) {
        case 4:
            listBulan4.add(object.getString("total"));
            break;
        case 5:
            listBulan5.add(object.getString("total"));
            break;
        case 6:
            listBulan6.add(object.getString("total"));
            break;
        }
    }

    Map < String, ArrayList < String >> map = new HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> ();
    map.put("total1", listBulan6);
    map.put("total2", listBulan5);
    map.put("total3", listBulan4);

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Below is Code.

```
package org.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SOActivity extends Activity {

    String string = "{\"GetReportResult\":[{\"bulan\":\"4\",\"total\":\"2448\",\"type\":\"CHEESE1K\",\"uang\":\"8847823\"},{\"bulan\":\"4\",\"total\":\"572476\",\"type\":\"ESL\",\"uang\":\"5863408410\"},{\"bulan\":\"4\",\"total\":\"46008\",\"type\":\"ESL500ML\",\"uang\":\"234498301\"},{\"bulan\":\"5\",\"total\":\"5703\",\"type\":\"CHEESE1K\",\"uang\":\"134929306\"},{\"bulan\":\"5\",\"total\":\"648663\",\"type\":\"ESL\",\"uang\":\"6645764498\"},{\"bulan\":\"5\",\"total\":\"51958\",\"type\":\"WHP\",\"uang\":\"631994613\"},{\"bulan\":\"6\",\"total\":\"6190\",\"type\":\"CHEESE1K\",\"uang\":\"104527773\"},{\"bulan\":\"6\",\"total\":\"443335\",\"type\":\"ESL\",\"uang\":\"4540123082\"},{\"bulan\":\"6\",\"total\":\"30550\",\"type\":\"ESL500ML\",\"uang\":\"148302378\"}]}";
    Map < String, ArrayList < String >> map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        map = new HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> ();
        try {
            ArrayList < String > listBulan4 = new ArrayList < String > ();
            ArrayList < String > listBulan5 = new ArrayList < String > ();
            ArrayList < String > listBulan6 = new ArrayList < String > ();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetReportResult");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                int bulanValue = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("bulan"));

                switch (bulanValue) {
                case 4:
                    listBulan4.add(object.getString("total"));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    listBulan5.add(object.getString("total"));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    listBulan6.add(object.getString("total"));
                    break;
                }
            }

            map.put("total1", listBulan6);
            map.put("total2", listBulan5);
            map.put("total3", listBulan4);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("test", map.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: I got this error:
`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value jsonString of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: @blankon91 Man insted of jsonString Put your JSON block there

Comment: I've done that can you check this out for more detail:
http://www.pastie.org/4164098

Comment: this is what I get on my log = 06-28 13:50:18.448: I/test(366): {}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13140/discussion-between-blankon91-and-vipul-shah)

Comment: well, I adapt it like this pastie.org/4164190

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map.

The keys in the Map are the bulan values that you want totals for.

Iterate over the array and update the sum for the relevant bulan value.

Comment: I didn't get it :( can you give me more specific example?

Answer (score 1):

I think this line make problem

bulan==6

Try this way...

bulan.equals("6")

I think it help you.

Thanks

Comment: ok, I've change it but the `"total"` values are not from `"bulan"`.equals("6"), it comes from all `"bulan"` :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct.

Hash map wont allow the dupilcate keys.Here you are trying to put duplicate keys.

So try with `ArrayList`

Sonething like this:

```
ArrayList < String > listBulan4 = new ArrayList < String > ();
  listBulan4.add(object.getString("total"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.
Just try

```
  if (bulan.equals("6")){
  map.put("total1", e.getString("total")); // I want the "total" values are from       specified bulan (e.g. bulan == 6)
}
else if (bulan.equals("5")){
     map.put("total2", e.getString("total")); // I want the "total" values are from specified bulan (e.g. bulan == 5)
 }
  else if (bulan.equals("4")){
     map.put("total3", e.getString("total")); // I want the "total" values are from specified bulan (e.g. bulan == 4)
}
```

Comment: The values will be overwritten in loop